# How can I view the HTML output of a .Net Razor page before the server encapsulates it?

Tags: c#, .net, razor

I'm writing a Blazor Server App in .net 6, and the output in the browser doesn't match my expectations. I'm new to many things in the world of Web development, including HTML; so I'd like to be able to see the HTML before the server packages it to go to the client.  I've done a ton of searching, but come up blank.

There are two specific reasons why I want to do this, but it seems like a valuable debugging tool regardless:

1. I want to find out why the top row is different from the rest.
2. I want to find out how the *id* field is showing up in the HTML so I can access the elements by those IDs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code from the Razor page

```
@inject AppState AppState
@inherits Picle3.Functions.StringFuncs
@implements IDisposable
@inject IJSRuntime JS;


<table class="gridHeader">
     <tr><td>Puzzle</td><td>Grid</td></tr>
 <tr><td>@AppState.CurrentPuzzle.Puzzle_ID</td><td>@AppState.CurrentPuzzle.Grid_ID</td></tr>

</table>
<table class="picleGrid">   
<tr>
        @for(int colCounter = 0; colCounter < AppState.CurrentPuzzle.Columns; colCounter++)
        {
            string sWord = AppState.CurrentPuzzle.TargetWord.WordText.Substring(colCounter, 1);
            <td ><input class="targetCell" type="text" value=@sWord /></td>
            
        }
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="picleGrid">
    @for(int iRowC = 0; iRowC < AppState.CurrentPuzzle.Rows; iRowC++)
    {
        int iRowChar = iRowC + 97;
        char rowChar = (char) iRowChar; 
        <tr>
            @for(int IColC = 0; IColC < AppState.CurrentPuzzle.Columns; IColC++)
            {
                int iColChar = IColC + 97;
                char colChar = (char)iColChar;

                string CellID = "cell" + rowChar.ToString() + colChar.ToString();

                <GridSquare name=@CellID id=@CellID SquareID=@CellID Row=@iRowC Col=@IColC BxBoxType=@AppState.CurrentPuzzle.Boxes[iRowC][IColC] STargetWord=@AppState.CurrentPuzzle.TargetWord.WordText  />
                functions.DebugOut(CellID);
                functions.DebugOut(CellID.Length.ToString());
            }

            <td style=@AppState.GuessFormats[@iRowC]>@AppState.Guesses[@iRowC]</td>
        </tr>

    }
</table> 

<p style=@AppState.SuccessStyle>SUCCESS!</p>
```

Here's the output. You can see that the top row is formatted differently than the succeeding rows.  To my mind the code to generate the HTML is identical (it's a copy/paste job) but it shows up with spaces between the cells.

[Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62pGv.png)

[This one has all the cells filled in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANRRU.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you explain more about `so I'd like to be able to see the HTML before the server packages it to go to the client.`?Do you mean you want to see the rendered html before page loading?If so,I think it is impossible.

Comment: @YiyiYou, yes.  I want to see the rendered HTML.  I hope it's possible because I don't know how else to debug it.

Comment: It's an interesting question - I don't really know for sure. But in general (ignoring the fact that you *could* manipulate the html on the client side, with javascript for instance) - the rendered html *sent* to the client is the html *received* by the client. I think you are overthinking this. To see the HTML use the inspector tools in your browser, it is really as simple as that. Your first row looks different because it is different - it has letters in the squares, whereas the others do not. The main thing here you are dealing with is the CSS for the table - designing its appearance.

Comment: @topsail, I've added another image.  This one has all the cells in the second table completed by the user.

Comment: And you're right about the inspector tools--this is what happens when you take a 25-year break from actually writing code professionally.  Of course, those led me to a different set of questions...

Comment: Okay so that's progress. I can't tell for sure but it looks like the D-E-L-T-A row is in the table that uses td's containing `input` elements (with a class of targetCell), and the "X" rows are in the table that has .... well, that code is more confusing. There seems to be a `GridSquare` element in use to create `tr` elements, as well as @AppState guesses to create `td` elements. In any case - these two types of rows are quite different in both the html and the css I think.